# JQuery working in chrome but not in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

This JQuery is working in chrome but it is not working in IE

```
$('body').append("<style>.homeBannerQuote {\r\n width:100%;\r\n height: 300px;\r\n}\r\n\r\n\r\n.bannerBG {\r\n background: url(https:\/\/someImageURL.png) 0 0 no-repeat;\r\n background-size:650px auto;\r\n background-position: 100% 25%;\r\n \r\n}\r\n\r\n\r\n\/* Headlines *\/\r\n\r\n.bannerBG h1, .bannerBG h2, #content table:first-of-type td:nth-child(2) h2 {\r\n\tmargin: 0;\r\n font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;\r\n text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;\r\n font-weight:bold;\r\n margin-left:5%;\r\n}\r\n\r\n.bannerBG h1 {\r\n\tfont-size: 3em;\r\n\tcolor: #FA9E00;\r\n margin-top:200px;\r\n}\r\n\r\n.bannerBG h2, #content table:first-of-type td:nth-child(2) h2 {\r\n\tfont-size: 2.4em;\r\n\tcolor: #fff;\r\n margin-bottom: 3%;\r\n}\r\n\r\n #content table:first-of-type td:nth-child(2) h2 {\r\n text-align:center;\r\n margin: 40px auto 20px auto;\r\n}\r\n\r\n\/* Quote Box *\/\r\n\r\n#content table:first-of-type td:nth-child(2) {\r\nbackground:#066DB5;\r\n}\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n#quotedropdowns {\r\n left: 688px !important;\r\n top: 100px !important;\r\n width:250px !important;\r\n}\r\n.tundra .dijitTextBox {font-size:1.5em;}\r\n#widget_states {width:150px;}\r\n\r\n\/* Button *\/\r\n\r\n.whitetext.smoothbox {\r\n\tborder-radius: 3px;\r\n background:#ff8a00;\r\n display:block;\r\n width:200px;\r\n height:20px;\r\n padding:5px;\r\n text-align:center;\r\n margin:auto;\r\n}\r\n\r\n#quotebuttontext {\r\n left:688px !important;\r\n top:190px !important;\r\n }\r\n\r\ntable#emailAddressForm {\r\n display: none;\r\n}<\/style>");
```

I think there might be some issue with nth-child,
I tried using `td:first-child + td` , but it is still not working in IE. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: image has been changed but the font , colour and size of text can not be modified.

Comment: what is the version of IE? because there are some workarounds on some versions.

Comment: I am using IE 11 ( 11.0.9600)

Comment: but it would be great if it is all browser compatible

Comment: hi Alexi, Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the `nth-child` is not supported in IE. You can use this site to track what you can or cannot use: https://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

But the `first-child` should work since its supported by IE: https://caniuse.com/#search=first-child

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried the first-child but still it is not working. Will you please guide me what should I change in the code?